# Compare vector to subset of row in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame "dat" and a numeric vector "test":

```
code <- c("A22", "B15", "C03")
v.1 <- 1:3
v.2 <- 3:1
v.3 <- c(2, NA, 2)
bob <- c("yes", "no", "no")
dat <- data.frame(code, v.1, v.2, v.3, bob, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test <- c(3, 1, 2)
```

I want to find the row in the data.frame where the second to fourth columns ("v.1", "v.2", "v.3") contain the same values as the vector, in the same order, and return the value from the "code"-column (in this case "C03").

I tried

```
dat[dat[, 2:4] == test]$code
```

and

```
which(apply(dat, 1, function(x) all.equal(dat[, 2:4], test)) == FALSE)
```

both of which do not work.

*I would prefer a solution with base R.*

Comment: row.names(subset(dat, dat$v.1 == test[1] & dat$v.2 == test[2] &dat$v.3 == test[3])) returns the rows you want. If you want to know the "code" value for these rows add to subset() function select="code". It helps you @what?

Comment: @MarioM. That works, but for that solution I would have to type all the column names from the data.frame and all the indices for the vector which is somewhat unhandy for large data sets.

Comment: to make it work with your 2nd option: `which(apply(dat[, 2:4], 1, function(x) all(x==test)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to replicate the 'test' to make the lengths equal before doing the comparison

```
dat[2:4] == test[row(dat[2:4])]
```

If we need the 'code'

```
dat$code[rowSums(dat[2:4] == test[row(dat[2:4])], na.rm = TRUE)==3]
#[1] C03
```

Comment: To get the rows for which they coincide, I will add: `dat$code[which(apply(dat[2:4] == test[col(dat[2:4])],1,sum)==length(test))]`

Comment: @akrun For some reason, your solution, when used with my real data instead of the sample data in the question, returns the correct code and a number of NAs: `"P040105" NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA`, while the solution from R18's comment returns only the code.

Comment: @what Can you try `dat$code[rowSums(dat[2:4] == test[row(dat[2:4])])==3]`

Comment: @akrun The reason is, some of my rows contain NAs. `rowSums(... , na.rm = TRUE)` solves that problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your second option (with `which`) does not work for several problems: using `apply` on whole `dat` converts it to a `matrix` of `character`, you're actually not using `x`, the function argument and you should use `all` instead of `all.equal` and probably `TRUE` instead of `FALSE` (the comparison is actually not needed).

You can modify it a bit to make it work:

```
which(apply(dat[, 2:4], 1, function(x) all(x==test)))
[1] 3
```

Or

```
dat[apply(dat[, 2:4], 1, function(x) all(x==test)), "code"]
[1] C03
```

Answer (score 1):

With `apply` we can `paste` the columns together and check which row has the same value as that of `test` when pasted together and selected the column `code` of respective row.

```
dat[apply(dat[2:4], 1, paste0, collapse = "|") == 
                       paste0(test, collapse = "|"), "code"]

#[1] C03
```